# Spark: Incremental collect() to a partition causes OutOfMemory in Heap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a following code. Essentially I need to print RDD to a console, so I am collecting large RDD in smaller chunks by collecting it per partition. This is to avoid collecting entire RDD at once. When monitoring the heap and GC log, it seems like nothing is ever being GC'd. Heap keeps on growing until it hits OutOfMemory error. If my understanding is correct, in below once println statement is executed for collected RDDs, they won't be needed so it is safe to GC, but that's not what I see in the GC log each call to collect accumulates until OOM. Does anyone know why collected data is not being GC'd?

```
 val writes = partitions.foreach { partition =>
      val rddPartition = rdds.mapPartitionsWithIndex ({ 
        case (index, data) => if (index == partition.index) data else Iterator[Words]()
      }, false).collect().toSeq
      val partialReport = Report(rddPartition, reportId, dateCreated)
      println(partialReport.name) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is huge, most probably master node cant handle it and would shutdown. You may try writing them to file (eg saveAsTextFile), then read each file again

Comment: The issue was, heap of the driver program was 500MB instead of 8GB we configured it to be. Therefore driver genuinely did not have sufficient memory to execute program and perform GC at the same time. Therefore GC could not keep up with execution of the application and eventually ran out of memory. And we couldn't see this until help of VisualVM...

Answer (score 0):

`collect()` creates an array containing all the elements of the RDD.

It cannot be garbage collected before it is fully created! Hence the OOM.

There can be way around it depending on what `Report` is actually doing.

Comment: If you read my description, I clearly states we collect for each partition and we do it to avoid collecting for entire RDD.

Comment: A partition is not necessarily small.

Comment: But why does it accumulates in heap? It should be GCd once done printing it. My question is why is data collected is accumulating in heap.