# With Spark Java RDDs, how can I process individual task results immediately as each one completes without waiting for collect()?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running a Spark RDD via collect().  Each individual task takes a long time to process, and the result set returned by collect() is very large:

```
   List<Result> manyResults =
      javaSparkContext
      .parallelize(tasks, tasks.size())
      .map(task -> task.process())
      .collect();
```

I need to process the Results on the driver.

Instead of waiting for all the Results to complete, I would simply like to process each Result individually *as each one completes*.

Is there a way to do this in Spark? i.e. iterate through the task Responses as each one completes?

Comment: Why do you need to process records on the driver? Also, have you thought about the case of *some* partitions failing in the execution of `process()`?

Comment: wont marks as duplicate but similar to this  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046692/spark-incremental-collect-to-a-partition-causes-outofmemory-in-heap

Comment: ernest_k: without getting into the details too much, the driver has access to external resources that the workers do not.  The responses individually are large, but if I can iterate through them on the driver I can discard most of the largeness during assembly.  Which would avoid the memory issues I have of waiting for them all first.

Answer (score 2):

Either you push your logic to be distributed as well (e.g. using a udf) or you can create a similar process in spark streaming and work with small batches

Comment: Thanks Arnon, but unfortunately I can't split the job up any further (see my comment above to ernest_k).  Since collect() is just assembling a List, conceptually it seems like it would be straightforward to just allow iterative access to those List objects as they arrive (like a BlockingQueue for example)?  Would be a useful option to help manage driver memory usage.